# How to set a specific header height for groupbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

As the title say, I need to know how can I set a specific header height for a GroupBox, suppose I've this:

```
<GroupBox Header="Test">

</GroupBox>
```

this will display an header height based on the content of the header, but is possible also set a specific header height? How?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a string for setting the `GroupBox` `Header` property, use directly a `TextBlock`, something like that:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="High Header" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MinHeight="100" />
    </GroupBox.Header>

    <Button Content="Button1" />
</GroupBox>
```